# Getting UTF-8 filenames to work with PHP ZipArchive

Tags: php, utf-8

I have a file that I want to add to a Zip with PHP, which is encoded in UTF-8. Here is the filename: 'µ漢字ääÖÅ.txt'.

Now, to get this file even to save to the filesystem I had to do this:

```
$filename = "µ漢字ääÖÅ.txt";
$codepage = 'Windows-' . trim(strstr(setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0), '.'), '.');
$encoded_filename = iconv('UTF-8', $codepage.'//IGNORE', $filename);
file_put_contents($encoded_filename, "text");
```

Now when I want to add the file to the ziparchive I use the following code:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip', \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$zip->addFile($encoded_filename, $encoded_filename);
$zip->close();
```

Which results in a zip file containing the file name 'ÁõõÍ+.txt'. How do I get it to save correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an answer (sort of). In the example above `$encoded_filename` was changed from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 encoding to save to the filesystem. I have no idea why but Windows-1252 works when saving directly to the filesystem but NOT when saving to a zip using ZipArchive.

To fix this I had to encode the $filename yet again to a different encoding, CP858.

Example:

```
$filename = "µ漢字ääÖÅ.txt";

//encode to windows-1252 to save to the filesystem
$encoded_filename = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$filename);
file_put_contents($encoded_filename, "text");

//put in a zip file
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip', \ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
//encode as CP858 to save into zip file
$zip->addFile($encoded_filename, iconv("UTF-8", "CP858//IGNORE", $filename));
$zip->close();
```

In the above example it still doesn't handle the Japanese characters in the file name, but at least it handles European characters which will have to do for the time being.

Comment: That saved a lot of time for me, iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$filename); did the trick for me... iconv("UTF-8", "CP858//IGNORE", $filename) did not had any change however.

Comment: @GAMITG @ user1578653 please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154025/php-ziparchive-dont-support-utf8-files-for-open