# Can't create a zip archive with utf8-named cyrillic file

Tags: php, windows, php-ziparchive

I try to create zip-archive with file фыфыфы.cs next way:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '111.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) {           
    $zip->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'фыфыфы.cs');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

But the archive wasn't created. I tried to view the number of files in the archive after addFile call with:

```
die($zip->numFiles);
```

But I got 0.

When I renamed file to zzz.cs, the archive was created successfully. What's wrong?

I use Windows 8 at my PC.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068536/getting-utf-8-filenames-to-work-with-php-ziparchive), but it didn't work for me. A got the empty $encoded_filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting UTF-8 filenames to work with PHP ZipArchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068536/getting-utf-8-filenames-to-work-with-php-ziparchive)

Answer (score 0):

for fix this I had to encode the $filename yet again to a different encoding, CP858.

**Example:**

```
$filename = "фыфыфы.cs";

//encode to windows-1252 to save to the filesystem
$encoded_filename = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$filename);
file_put_contents($encoded_filename, "text");

//put in a zip file
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
//encode as CP858 to save into zip file
$zip->addFile($encoded_filename, iconv("UTF-8", "CP858//IGNORE", $filename));
$zip->close();
```

You can implement this method for your code.

Comment: After $encoded_filename = iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$filename); I got empty string in $encoded_filename, so, file couldn't be created.