# PHP: ZipArchive addFile rename not work for non latin character

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I use this code:

```
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();
$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zipArchive->addFile($file, 'فایل با عنوان فارسی.mp3');
```

After download zip file, in folder i find this title:

```
┌å┌»┘ê┘å┘ç ┘ü╪▒╪▓┘å╪»┘à╪º┘å ╪▒╪º ╪¿╪º ╪╣╪▒╪╢┘ç ╪¿╪º╪▒ ╪¿█î╪º┘ê╪▒█î┘à ╪ƒ ╪»╪▒╪│ ┌»┘ü╪¬╪º╪▒.mp3
```

But i want to see this :

```
فایل با عنوان فارسی.mp3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting UTF-8 filenames to work with PHP ZipArchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068536/getting-utf-8-filenames-to-work-with-php-ziparchive)

Comment: i use it, but not work for me